# Raspberry Pi to website stream

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, streaming, nfs, hls

there are countless howtos describing how to stream from Raspberry Pi to somewhere, I'm somehow lost and tired of trying different configurations.

My resources:

1. Raspberry pi camera v2
2. Raspberry Pi v3
3. OpenWRT router
4. 20 Mbit upload fiber connection with static IP
5. cheap VPS with static IP (100/100 MBit)
6. Some general linux skills.

My goal:
Get (public) live stream from the camera via web browser for a few clients.

That should be more than enough to have live quite good quality streaming, but it turned out it's not that easy.

First I've tried with raspicam, netcat, mplayer - It was bad, unstable, required binary mplayer on the client side.

Then I've discovered uv4l which was quite OK, but not perfect. I either had a high quality stream via binary mplayer via h264, or a 1-2 fps stream via mjpeg, I did some tricks to embed it into iframe on the website... It was working for some time, but it consumed the entire network, was quite CPU demanding.

The embedding on the website was far from being perfect. And then I came across ffmpeg solution. My current parameters are:

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 40 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -codec:a copy -f ssegment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 40 -sc_threshold 0 -segment_wrap 30 out%03d.ts`

and the output is a NFSv4 mounted directory to the VPS, with apache2 and flowplayer on the server.

Works quite OK, but could be better.

Pros:

1. No matter the number of clients the local connection is equally loaded
2. I profit from Raspberry Pi hardware encoding
3. I got 40 fps, FullHD

Cons:

1. As the segment is being terminated it needs to be written via NFS to the VPS - and the stream chokes on that. Depening on how large the segment is the stream freezes for 3-15 seconds (time needed to write the file over NFS? ).
2. The network upstream gets saturated as the Pi uploads the segment
3. A few segments (a minute or two) delay in stream

What do You recommend to countermeasure at least 1 and 2? I was thinking about doing the NFS "the other way", but constant write to microSD could kill my card.

ffmpeg on the server is an option, but I probably don't have cpu power to transcode it on the fly.

I don't expect a definite and "the right and only answer", but would be grateful for ideas.

Comment: Have you considered using a YouTube stream in private mode? That makes thingsa a lot easier. If not, use `ffmpeg ... -f segment ... ` on the RasPi side, then copy the *.ts and *.m3u8 via (S)FTP, this works pretty perfect.

Comment: @EugenRieck Is it OK to have 24h private YouTube full HD stream? It could do.

I've tried  SFTP using ffmpeg build-in SFTP mode, the inter-segment freeze was significantly worse : (

Comment: I do this all the time - no problem

Comment: Currently I migrated to: 

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 40 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -codec:a copy -f flv rtmp://<retransmission node>/live/stream`

And the retransmission node is nginx.